# gulp inject relative file paths

Tags: gulp, gulp-plugin

I have a file, `testboot.js`, that I want to inject import statements like so:

```
import "../app/app.spec";
import "../app/navbar/navbar.spec";
```

**Note that the import statement is relative to `testboot.js`.** I am having trouble figuring out a clean way of doing this using gulp. Here is my partial gulp task:

```
gulp.task("inject", function (cb) {
    gulp
        .src("src/client/app/**/*.spec.js")
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(filenames("inject"))
        .on("end", function () {
            filenames.get("inject").map(function(e){
                // do something
            });
            util.log("in end"); // never called
            cb();
        });
});
```

But the "end" handler is never called. Can anyone help me out with this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're listening for the wrong event. From the [Node.js documentation on `Stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end):

> The `'finish'` and `'end'` events are from the parent `Writable` and `Readable` classes respectively. The `'finish'` event is fired after `stream.end()` is called and all chunks have been processed by `stream._transform()`, `'end'` is fired after all data has been output which is after the callback in `stream._flush()` has been called.

That means you either have to listen for the `'finish'` event:

```
gulp.task("inject", function (cb) {
  gulp
    .src("src/client/app/**/*.spec.js")
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(filenames("inject"))
    .on("finish", function () {
        filenames.get("inject").map(function(e){
            // do something
        });
        util.log("in end");
        cb();
    });
});
```

Or you have to ensure that the callback in [`stream._flush()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_flush_callback) is invoked, e.g. with `gulp.dest()`:

```
gulp.task("inject", function (cb) {
  gulp
    .src("src/client/app/**/*.spec.js")
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(filenames("inject"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .on("end", function () {
        filenames.get("inject").map(function(e){
            // do something
        });
        util.log("in end");
        cb();
    });
});
```